# Remove Line Feeds and first character from large (2GB) XML file on Windows

Tags: powershell, ssis

I have an XML file from a third party and it is broken up into non-static length lines delimited with Line Feeds.

There is also a strange first character that needs to be stripped from the file.

I am fairly certain that the two items above are causing issues loading the XML file with SSIS. If I remove them by hand (from a smaller sample), the XML file loads fine thru SSIS.

At this point I've tried using both SSIS and Powershell to attempt to fix the file.

SSIS resulted in strangely adding delimiters back in.

My attempts using Powershell were a little more fruitful on a small subset of the data, but my actual file will regularly be in excess of 2GB and I keep getting System.OutOfMemory exceptions. I have increased the "maxmemorypershellmb" for Powershell (and restarted winrm) but it seems to have had no effect preventing the OutOfMemory error.

Current Powershell attempts that work with a small sample file:

```
-join ((Get-Content "C:\Code\input.xml") -replace '^\w$', '') | Set-Content -Path "C:\Code\output-nolinefeed.xml"

-join ((Get-Content "C:\Code\output-nolinefeed.xml").substring(1) | Set-Content -Path "C:\Code\output-nolinefeed-removefirstchar.xml"
```

If both of the above commands run on the sample file, it will then import into SSIS (XML Source -> Derived Column -> SQL Server Destination).

Looking at it in Notepad++ (below), see how it appears to have some type of black smudge on the "less than" character. The other "less than" characters all appear normal. Also, the neon green is some type of space I can select as well.

When I open the file, it is UTF-8. Choosing Encoding -> Covert to ASCII results in the space and "less than" character being converted to a single question mark.

[image]

Reasons for weird first character and line feeds aside (assuming both cannot be handled with SSIS), at this point I need some command line editor that will gracefully handle large files.

Comment: 2GB is the maximum size of XML ssis can handle, you'll be pushing the limits

Comment: Hi Jayvee, do you have a source for this? On this link the author loads a file much bigger than 2GB: http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/01/26/import-wikipedia-articles-into-sql-server-with-ssis/

Comment: Reading this article it seems that there is no limit although this refers to an xml source component, the (bad)experiences I have with 2gb+ xml files are related to validation using the xml task. 2gb is still the limit for a blob sql server, I'll find out more precisely in what cases this affects SSIS. If are reading it as a flat file and not planning to load it to sql server you will not be affected by the 2gb limit in any case. Is your new string split into many or is just one big string?

Comment: I do intend to load the XML into a table. I've moved on to using PS on the command line to strip line feeds.

Comment: @Jayvee - editing this to not require SSIS

Comment: What exactly is the strange first character. Also, exactly why are the linefeeds a problem?

Comment: The linefeeds seem to be a problem when I attempt to load the XML file into a SQL table using SSIS. Since I've been able to work with a smaller portion of the file, I tried editing out the strange first character, and then attempted to load thru SSIS. I get "The XML Source was unable to read the XML data". Stripping the first character and all linefeeds and the XML loads using SSIS. I'll update my question...

Comment: Can you post an example showing where the linefeeds are located in the XML?

Comment: Use a hex editor to check what the "smudged less than" char is. Maybe it's  some weird Unicode char? [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Foxe editor for monster XML files:

http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm

It is astoundingly quick and seems reliable as far as I've used it.

Apparently it has a scripting language based on C++, but I havent tried that.